# Unwated Looping with a simple family tree Prolog Program

Tags: prolog

A strange problem presents itself in the programme as when some of the clauses such as uncle,aunt and cousin are used they give answers which are obviously not logically equivelent, e.g. `uncle(david, Y).` should give all of the people david is an uncle of but instead gives all children listed and then loops them a further two times.

If anyone could help me with this it would be great, I'm only starting to understand a few ins and outs of the language and have come stuck in mu debugging of this.

```
parents(jennifer, george, noreen).
parents(david, george, noreen).
parents(georgejr, george, noreen).
parents(scott, george, noreen).
parents(joanne, george, noreen).
parents(jessica, david, edel).
parents(clara, david, edel).
parents(michael, david, edel).
parents(laura, georgejr, susan).
parents(anna, scott, siobhan).

father(X, Y) :- parents(Y, X, _).
male(X) :- father(X, _).

mother(X, Y) :- parents(Y, _, X).
female(X) :- mother(X, _).

grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), father(Z, Y).
grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).

grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).
grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), father(Z, Y).

brother(X, Y) :- male(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y).

sister(X, Y) :- female(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y).

uncle(X, Y) :- brother(X, Z), father(Z, Y).

aunt(X, Y) :- sister(X, Z), father(Z, Y).

cousin(X, Y) :- father(M, X), father(N, Y), brother(M, N).
```

Answer (score 1):

An obvious problem in your code is in `brother/2` clause

```
brother(X, Y) :- male(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y).
```

`X` is brother of `Y` if `X` is male and `Z` is father of both.

If you don't impose that `X` is different from `Y`, `X` result brother of itself, so `david` result brother of `david` and uncle of his children.

Try with

```
brother(X, Y) :- male(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), X \= Y.
```

Comment: Thank you, I was completely oblivious to that slight error.